# Headless testing in the browser vs in the buffer with Selenium

Tags: html, css, selenium, cucumber

I am using Selenium in the browser and using it with xvfb via the headless ruby gem. When I run my test in the browser the tests passes. When I run the same test using HEADLESS, it fails at the attempt to select a checkbox element at this point:

```
<div id="edit-field-industry-und" class="form-checkboxes">
    <li id="50" class="half selected">
        <div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-industry-und-50">
            <input id="edit-field-industry-und-50" class="form-checkbox" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="50" name="field_industry[und][50]">
            <label class="option" for="edit-field-industry-und-50">Aerospace</label>
        </div>
    </li>
</div>
```

***NOTE:*** The input in the HTML is hidden!!

The **ERROR:
Element is not clickable at point (849.433349609375, 21). Other element would receive the click:  (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)**

Not sure why the designers did this (A Drupal site btw), but my suspicion is that the check-box element is wrapped in a **div** as a **li** (list element).

My question is why am I able to click the button in the browser, but not in the buffer? Also, would there be a work around to say check an object that is by invisible in the css file?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried PhantomJS (http://phantomjs.org/) for headless testing? It works perfectly well with Selenium. Also you can use JavascriptExecutor for clicking hidden elements.

Comment: No, xvfb with a real browser is the correct option for testing. 1) Phantomjs integration with Webdriver has not been maintained in 2 1/2 years (https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver). 2) No user will ever browse to your site using the phantomjs browser 3) Chrome + xvfb is faster than phantomjs in many circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time when this happens, you are running a different browser resolution in xvfb, which is causing the css to behave differently. You can verify with: `browser.window.size` and address the issue with `browser.window.resize_to 1600, 1200` or `browser.window.maximize`

Comment: Thanks I will give this a shot